# how to submit form with enctype multipart/form-data in jquery

Tags: jquery, forms, multipartform-data

i'm using form with enctype multipart/form-data for uploading photo, so below is my code for normal form submit,

```
$.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    url: loadUrl,  
    cache: false,  
    success: function(html){  
      $(outputLocation).html(html);  
    }
});
```

how this should alter, so its applicable for multipart/form-data type form in jquery

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check out the below plugin if it helps -

http://www.fyneworks.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload/#tab-Overview

Answer (score 1):

Here some [interesting instructions](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1273-Setting-Form-EncType-Dynamically-To-Multipart-Form-Data-In-IE-Internet-Explorer-.htm) by Ben Nadel.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit files over XMLHttpRequest (since you can't read the data from the user's HDD in JS).

jQuery doesn't have built in support to deal with file inputs, you'll need to find a [plugin](http://www.google.co.uk/search?hl=en&source=hp&q=jquery%20file%20upload&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) or an alternative.